# How can I use Rubymine to automatically convert a ruby block from curly braced style to begin..end style and vice versa?

Tags: ruby, rubymine

I'm using Rubymine and wondering, how can I convert a block from curly braced notation to begin..end and vice versa?

for example

```
loop do
end
```

to

```
loop {}
```

Comment: Can you share more details what is there and what is expected?

Comment: @SatishakumarAwati I've added more information.

Comment: Put your cursor on `do`, press `Alt`+`Enter`. You'll see the option.

Comment: @MarkThomas Many thanks! It works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To toggle between `do`..`end` blocks and ``` {``} ``` blocks, place your cursor on the `do` (or open bracket) and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You see the option to toggle.